# Terminating child process using signals in python multiprocessing

Tags: python, linux, signals, python-multiprocessing

I have a bit of code that's running two worker processes, similar to the following:

```
for queue in queues:
   process = multiprocessing.Process(name=queue.name, target=worker, args=(args,))
```

I'm turning this particular program into a daemon, so I'm also registering some signal handlers to catch SIGTERM, so the parent process can make sure the children terminate.  Something like this:

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, cleanup)

def cleanup(signal, frame)
  for job in jobs:
    if job.is_alive():
      job.terminate()
  sys.exit(0)
```

I'm getting some strange looking errors when I do this, including things like "can only test a child process", and "KeyError in module 'threading'".

Without posting the full stack strace (which is long), is there anything fundamentally wrong about the way I'm going about this?  IE: Should I not be terminating process within a signal handler in this fashion?

Comment: So I moved the termination and sys.exit() out from the handler, into the main process.  Now the signal handler just sets a variable indicating that the parent should terminate all child processes.  One thing I didn't realize was the handler was being called multiple times, I believe by each child process, since signals propagate to the entire process group.  I added a lock to ensure the relevant handler code was executed once (setting of the kill variable), and then the main process now handles the cleanup.  It seems to be working now.